# Property not defined in CActiveDateProvider

Tags: yii

Controller:

```
<?php
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('ClubMember', array(
                'criteria'=>array(                     
                    'select'=>'Count(`fb_user_id`) as total,  YEAR(`registerdate`) as year,registerdate',
                    'group' =>'WEEK(`registerdate`), YEAR(`registerdate`)',
                    'order' =>'registerdate DESC',                    
                    'condition'=>"t.club_id = '$club'",                                  
                ),
                'pagination'=>array(
                    'pageSize'=>10,
                ),                
            ));
?>
```

View page:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
            'itemView'=>'_dispaly',
        )); ?>
```

View Partial page:

```
<?php echo $data->year; ?>
```

When I tried to get `$data->year`, I got the following error:

```
Property "ClubMember.year" is not defined.
```

How can I access the property 'year' from above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your class you have to add them as public properties

```
class ClubMember extends CActiveRecord
{
    public $year;
    public $total;
    ....
    ...
}
```